# How to check all input boxes are not empty or equal to 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a form with many input boxes. I want to make a function that will go through each box and determine if any of the boxes are 0 or empty.

The **user only needs to fill one one** of the input boxes. If they fill all of them, that is fine too. But one is the minimum requirement. Otherwise an error alert should appear.

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return checkInputs()" name="inputData" id="inputData">

  Socks <input class="text-center" value="0" type="text" id="socks" name="socks">

  Underwear <input class="text-center" value="0" type="text" id="underwear" name="underwear">

  Ties <input class="text-center" value="0" type="text" id="ties" name="ties">

  Pants <input class="text-center" value="0" type="text" id="pants" name="pants">


  <a href="#" onClick="checkInputs()"> Save</a>

</form>
```

And my JS

```
function checkInputs() {

    var flag=0;

    $("form#inputData :input[type=text]").each(function(){
        var input = $(this); 
        if(input.val() > 0) {
          // all good
        } else { 
            flag=1; 
        }
    });

    if(flag==1){
        alert('Error!');
    } else {
        alert('Thanks!');
    }

}
```

My codePen is http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPmoma

Comment: I have check you codepen and all seems OK

Comment: @LesterVargas - do you get an alert saying Thanks

Comment: yep, can you provide combination that doesn't work for you?

Comment: i got thanks when all are 1

Comment: I have check to and all seems OK

Comment: Sorry - my question is that the user needs to choose at least 1 not all fields

Comment: Try to evaluate firs all your inputs an then determinate which one has a number, may be you have to put the result in an array an then verify if the array has values else throw an error message

Comment: I put an example I hope it can help you

Comment: An additional comment unrelated. If you want only quantity numbers in the field, you could use type="number"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
function checkInputs() {

    var flag=0;
  var result = new Array();

    $("form#inputData :input[type=text]").each(function(){
        var input = $(this); 
        if(input.val() > 0 && input.val() !== '' ) {
            result.push(input.val());
        } 
    });

    if(result.length > 0){
        alert('thanks')
    } else {
        alert('error!'); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Flawless victory. Can you explain the code a little.

Comment: first evaluate all your inputs an then check which one has a number or is not empty, then put the result in an array and then verify if the array has values, else throw an error message

Answer (score 1):

for simpler code, you can also use jquery selectors:

```
$('input[type=text]:not([value=""],[value=0])')
```

*Edit: with a conditional:

```
var len = $('input[type=text]:not([value=""],[value=0])').length;
if(len>0) alert('thanks');
else alert('error!');
```

Comment: Superb. An example with a conditional?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid: Edited to add contitional

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by the other answers, the critical flaw in your design is that the `$('.alert-danger')` is modified for each iteration of [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/). Below is one possible solution with the explanation to follow:

```js
function checkInputs() {

  $('.alert-danger').show();

  $("form#inputData :input[type=text]").each(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if (parseInt(input.val(), 10) > 0) {
      $('.alert-danger').hide();
      return false;
    }
  });
  
  if($('.alert-danger').is(':visible')) {
      alert("Danger!");
  } else {
      alert("Thanks!");
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.alert-danger {
  color: #a94442;
  background: #f2dede;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebccd1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return checkInputs()" name="inputData" id="inputData">

<div style="display:none" class="alert-danger">You need enter at least 1 quantity for any or all of these choices. 
</div>


  <br /><br />
  <input class="text-center" value="0" type="text" id="socks" name="socks"><br />
  <input class="text-center" value="0" type="text" id="underwear" name="underwear"><br />
  <input class="text-center" value="0" type="text" id="ties" name="ties"><br />
  <input class="text-center" value="0" type="text" id="ties" name="ties"><br />
  <br /><br />
  <a href="#" onClick="checkInputs()"> Save</a>

</form>
```

You'll notice a few changes in the above code example from the one you provided. First, I removed the `flag` variable. By calling`.show()` and `.hide()` at the appropriate times, we can utilize the `.alert-danger`'s visibile presence as the key as to whether or not we show the error or hide the error.

The second change is that we're parsing the input box values using `parseInt(input.val(), 10)` before checking to see if the value is greater than `0`. By using the type conversion properties that `parseInt()` provides, we can filter out irrelevant content. For example the letter `"a"` will not validate as a legitimate value since its non numeric since `parseInt("a", 10) = NaN` and `NaN > 0`.

Finally, since you noted that only one value had to be set for validation to accept the input, I've added `return false;` to the `.each()` loop. With this line, the loop will *short circuit* as soon as one value validates correctly.

Comment: Only one of the fields is mandatory not all. If I put 1 in the second to last field you trigger danger - I only need to check one of the input boxes.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid Sorry, about this. I missed that part. Refactored the above code and it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

**The first issue** has been clearly explained by others - iteration.

**The second issue**. You're using a link to trigger the function. Do not forget that the default action of a link is to follow the link, even if it is to the same page or `'#'` in your case, which may cause the page to reload. Use `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the default action.

**Thirdly**, the `alert()` function s not a good debugging tool. The page refreshes as soon as you click ok on the alert and the page resets.

```js
$('.save').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var ok = $(this).closest('form').find(':text.text-center').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() > 0;
  });
  if( ok.length ) {
    $('.alert-danger').slideUp();
    $('.out').text('Thanks!');
  } else {
    $('.alert-danger').slideDown();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" name="inputData" id="inputData">

<div style="display:none" class="alert-danger">You need enter at least 1 quantity for any or all of these choices. 
</div>


  <br /><br />
  <input class="text-center" value="0" type="text" id="socks" name="socks"><br />
  <input class="text-center" value="0" type="text" id="underwear" name="underwear"><br />
  <input class="text-center" value="0" type="text" id="ties" name="ties"><br />
  <input class="text-center" value="0" type="text" id="ties" name="ties"><br />
  <br /><br />
  <a href="#" class="save"> Save</a>
  
  <div class="out"></div>

</form>
```